# Magento 2.2.0 missing admin developer configuration

Tags: configuration, system.xml, magento2.2.0

I tried to upgrade my Magento into 2.2.0. And I see that is missing `Advanced` and `Developer` items. Is it me? Why it's happening this?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check your Deployment Mode it is in Production.

To enable the developer tab menu under the Advanced You need to change it to **Developer Mode**

So run this command : **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer**

Clear the cache by running this command : **php bin/magento cache:clean**

> Now check Go to admin ->logged in ->click on stores
>   ->configuration->advanced -> you will see developer option  now.

Comment: does not work on magento 2.2.2

Comment: @Blueblazer172 - its working on magento 2.2.2 - kindly check your environment mode again !!

Comment: @ManthanDave The same issue exists with `Magento2.3` I have followed all these steps. But still the issue exists. Is there any other debugging method I can follow?

Comment: @Butterfly - From the Magento version 2.2.x on wards this configuration is completely removed ! so even though you are in a developer mode - it will not showcase this menu ! because it is completely removed by Magento itself. So you will not able to see the same.

Comment: @ManthanDave How can I enable template hin path then? Any idea,

Comment: @Butterfly - You can do it by command line, here is the command - php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable

Comment: @ManthanDave It helps. Thanks

Comment: @Butterfly - Happy to help you keep helping others !

Answer (score 8):

In `Magento 2.2` advance section has been removed,

> The ability to disable module output has been removed from Admin. If
>   you disabled module output from Admin in a previous release, you must
>   manually configure these settings. See Disable module output for
>   details.

[image]

You can read release note from this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html)

**EDIT**

`Developer` section is  there `Magento`team doesn't remove this feature. I checked in my fresh setup. Still you can debug this from below location

`vendor\magento\module-backend\etc\adminhtml\system.xml` and check If `developer`
 section is there or not. If its there then may be something wrong with Instillation process.

Comment: Okay the advanced section was removed, but the developer?

Comment: Developer section is there, please check it I checked in fresh Instillation and it's there.  see my edit @slayerbleast

Answer (score 0):

Keyur's answer solved my issue, but i wanted to add that for a site that has been migrated to Magento 2.2, the settings for this are migrated into the `core_config_data` database table. So if you are facing an issue where a module is disabled and there isn't a reference in the `/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/config.xml` file, you might find it in your DB.

[image]