# Google TAG MANAGER extension impossible located

Tags: magento2, google-tag-manager

I have installed via composer extension Google Tag Manager from Yireo:
https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/googletagmanager2

After install I have enable module (on below  screenshot can see that it is enable):

[image]

despite this, he is nowhere in my backend. Where can I find ?

Comment: run php bin/magento static-content:deploy & cache:cache  and check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`system.xml`](https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_GoogleTagManager2/blob/master/etc/adminhtml/system.xml) you can find it under:

> Stores > Configuration > Sales > Yireo GoogleTagManager

If not please flush your webshop cache storage.

> php bin/magento c:f

Comment: thanks I see extension is in Stores > Configuration > Sales > Yireo GoogleTagManager. On Github he said: Stores > Configuration >  Advanced. Once again thanks.

Comment: See my answer why you can not find https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195243/2589 @Sylvester

Comment: the following extension works great for us https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-google-tag-manager-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html