# Magento 2.3.4: How to serve end-users updated static files

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.3.4

We recently upgraded from 2.3.1 to 2.3.4-p2. However we're getting reports from end-users of some core functionality, such as the checkout process, breaking due to their browser serving outdated files (I assume files from before the upgrade).

Asking them to manually clear their cookies / cache fixes the issue on their end, however that doesn't sound like the proper solution.

We've already ran the following:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*
bin/magento s:up
bin/magento s:d:c
bin/magento s:s:d -f
bin/magento i:rei
bin/magento c:f
```

Is there any other proper ways to make sure end-users are being served up-to-date static resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static content signing

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html

The version parameter ensures latest version

If this is enabled it's a different issue. Perhaps a proxy cache has cached out of date page content. In which case you need to clear proxy cache after any deployment.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, what about if server is in production mode? I don't see the Developer option / menu when in production

Comment: Use shell command `bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign <value>`

Comment: But yes - it's hidden https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195239/magento-2-2-0-missing-admin-developer-configuration - possibly the single stupidest design decision I've ever come across in M2

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that out using the shell command!

Comment: Thanks, using the shell command enabled that option and that seems to be working!